# Evaluating the integral $\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}k e^{-i( t - x)k}k^{-i\omega/a}$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform, gamma-function

I am attempting to compute the vacuum expectation value for the energy density of a particular system (Quantum Field Theory). I come across the following integral $$\int_0^\infty   \mathrm{d}k \: e^{-i(t - x)k}k^{-i\omega/a} $$ where $t,x,k,\omega,a\in\mathbb{R}$. Mathematica gives me a conditional expression with constraints on the imaginary parts of $t,z,\omega,a$ which are not satisfied because they are all real parameters. I have tried using identities such as 
[Proof of $\Gamma(z) e^{i \pi z/2} = \int_0^\infty t^{z-1} e^{it}\, dt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549781/proof-of-gammaz-ei-pi-z-2-int-0-infty-tz-1-eit-dt) but then realised that they also require the same constraints. I also tried the substitution $\rho = ln(k)$ (here $k$ is a positive frequency) but encountered a similar issue.

Does anyone have suggestions to analytically evaluate this? My contour integration/complex analysis knowledge is fairly fundamental so would prefer a physicist's solution.

Comment: Well the integral may be divergent as the integrand does not tend to zero.

Comment: the integral may converge in the sense of distribution.

Comment: What does it mean for the integral to converge in the sense of distribution? How would I test that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral
$$\int_0^\infty k^{i p} e^{i x k} dk, \quad p, x \in \mathbb R$$
diverges. If that helps, the Fourier transform exists in the distributional sense, with the image being a singular functional:
$$\mathcal F[k^{i p} H(k)] = i e^{-\pi p /2} \Gamma(i p + 1) (x + i0)^{-i p - 1}, \\
(x + i0)^\lambda = x_+^\lambda + e^{i \pi \lambda} x_-^\lambda, \\
(x_\pm^\lambda, \phi) =
\int_0^\infty x^\lambda (\phi(\pm x) - \phi(0) H(1 - x)) dx +
 \frac {\phi(0)} {\lambda + 1}, \\
\operatorname{Re} \lambda = -1, \operatorname{Im} \lambda \neq 0.$$